# Как 1 раз обработать нажатие клавиши?

Tags: c++, winapi

Проблема заключается в том, что если зажать клавишу в итоге "case WM_KEYDOWN" будет возвращать клавишу постоянно.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Keyb_input/notify_wm_keydown.htm) Там достаточно информации для решения этой проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например можно

1. отлавливать `WM_KEYUP`, тогда будет отловлено только 1 "нажатие"
2. первый метод имеет недостаток, что если нажать и не отпускать, то событие долго не будет срабатывать, поэтому оптимальнее сделать так:

   ```
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        // выполнять действия, только если флаг нажатия сброшен
        if (isKeyPressed == false)
        {
            // сделать какие-то действия
            make_actions();

            // установить флаг нажатия
            isKeyPressed = true;
        }
        break;

    case WM_KEYUP:
        // сбросить флаг нажатия
        isKeyPressed = false;
        break;
   ```